# oracle join string to number not working by adding regexp_like

Tags: sql, oracle, join

oracle join string to number not working by adding regexp_like. For example,

```
Foo                           Bar
--------------                ------------
id varchar2(20)               id number(20,0)
```

Foo id can be number or any string (not number), e.g., 123, hello, world, 555, etc.

```
select foo.id,bar.id from Foo foo 
left join Bar bar on (regexp_like(foo.id, '^[0-9]+$') and foo.id=bar.id)
```

error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

foo.id=bar.id is evaluated only when foo.id is a number, right?

The following is working fine for mysql

```
select foo.id,bar.id from Foo foo 
left join Bar bar on (foo.id=bar.id)
```

But it causes the ORA-01722: invalid number for oracle. That is why "regexp_like" is added in join condition.

Comment: Hi @Sunnyday why Oracle database tag and this "The following is working fine for mysql" ? Thanks!

Comment: I know. I hope that the mysql version works for oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select foo.id
       , bar.id 
from Foo foo 
left join Bar bar on foo.id = to_char(bar.id);
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6218e2f90cd3fb7a93fcb5ddbc1d672)

Comment: @Sunnyday is this what you need ? Or?

Comment: converting number to char is working. But do you know why adding regexp_like was not working.

Comment: Ok, i will check but that was not a question. I suggest new question for that. Also I believe this answer should be marked as correct. I will try to find out why regexp_like is not working...

Comment: Please can you explain from this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2ca87df471ae2a2092a92e6d040df102
Why Is it that regexp_like is not working ? Thanks!

Comment: It is left join. different results.

Comment: I believe it is working fine it is just the understanding of what left join should do and what should where clause do is what is maybe problem here...

Answer (score 1):

Requires Oracle 12.2 or later:

```
select foo.id,bar.id
from   foo
       left join bar on bar.id = to_number(foo.id default 0 on conversion error);
```

(I expected it to work with `default null on conversion error` but it crashes the session.)

Regarding your question about why the original attempt using `regexp_like` doesn't work, it worked for me in 12.2.0.1. Probably in your case it was evaluating `foo.id = bar.id` first. It may be possible to hint or rewrite the query to force the regex to be applied first.

Comment: if (foo.id=bar.id) is evaluated first, it is a bug. But oracle has a lot of users, it should not be a bug. I am testing Oracle 11g.

Comment: Why is it a bug? The optimizer has no way of knowing that the `regex_like` filter will avoid the datatype conversion error. Should it always evaluate filter predicates before access predicates? There could be cases where that would give worse performance.